# I can't do "killall deluged"

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, ubuntu-server, deluge

I've been following [this guide](https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient) to setup a deluged service and client so I can download media files directly unto my server's drive. I'm trying to be thorough there since this is my first time trying to setup a server and I hit a wall when I try to run:

```
$ deluged
$ killall deluged
```

I get the error `[ERROR   ] 14:53:39 rpcserver:378 Couldn't listen on localhost:58846: [Errno 98] Address already in use.` and

```
deluged(8862): Operation not permitted
deluged: no process found
```

So I get that deluged is already running and can't start again, but why can't I kill the process?

Running `sudo systemctl status deluged` says the service is running. I am a bit confused now, do I have to have my process closed to create the default config. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.9.

Comment: Can you make a `ps aux | grep deluge` ?